# Get user groups from MS Azure Active Directory

Tags: java, azure, active-directory

I am trying to get all the groups a user belongs to. When i run the below code i get 405 error. Am i not calling the resources correctly? Was following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsersMemberships

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/groups", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public JSONArray getMembersOf(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    try {
           HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
           AuthenticationResult result =
               (AuthenticationResult) session.getAttribute(AuthHelper.PRINCIPAL_SESSION_NAME);
           String accessToken = result.getAccessToken();
           String tenant = session.getServletContext().getInitParameter("tenant");
           URL url =
               new URL(String.format("https://graph.windows.net/%s/users/userId@abc.onmicrosoft.com/getMemberGroups?api-version=2013-04-05",
                                     tenant, accessToken));
           HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           // Set the appropriate header fields in the request header.
           conn.setRequestProperty("api-version", "2013-04-05");
           conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", accessToken);
           conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata");
           String goodRespStr = HttpClientHelper.getResponseStringFromConn(conn, true);
           System.out.println("REsponse is --------------->>>>>  "+goodRespStr);
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: https://graph.windows.net/abc.onmicrosoft.com/users/userId@abc.onmicrosoft.com/getMemberGroups?api-version=2013-04-05
```

Comment: If the content of `accessToken` is just the JWT, then the authorization header should be: `conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);`

Comment: Also I'm not sure why the access token is in this String.format call: `String.format("https://graph.windows.net/%s/users/userId@abc.onmicrosoft.com/getMemberGroups?api-version=2013-04-05", tenant, accessToken)`. Shouldn't it be: `String.format("https://graph.windows.net/%s/users/userId@abc.onmicrosoft.com/getMemberGroups?api-version=2013-04-05", tenant)`?

Comment: I got it working. Actually i was using not using the correct uri. Seems 2013-04-05 version has "memberOf" instead of "getMemberGroups". Working fine now. Thanks !!

Comment: Actually i took the sample code (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-java) and was trying to make that work. Seems "String.format" has a typo there. Thanks, will correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, based on my understanding, I think you want to `get collection that contains the object IDs of the groups of which the user is a member` which is the Azure AD REST API [`Get Member Groups` for `Users`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/graphrbac/users#Users_GetMemberGroups). The error code returned from server seems to means `Method Not Allowed` which you can refer to the section `10.4.6 405 Method Not Allowed` of [HTTP RFC doc](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

I think the issue might be caused by using an outdated value of `api-version`, please using `1.6` instread of `2013-04-05` in your code and try again.

Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I got it resolved as mentioned in previous comment. "getMemberGroups" didn't worked in 1.6. Later i used "memberOf" with '2013-04-05' which helped.